# Take Text from Textbox and used it in a C

Tags: vb.net

Visual Basics 2010:

Two numbers are generated automatically. For example if the Random numbers generated are 2 and 3, you should press the button in 2nd row and 3rd column. I have created the random number generator:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 0 To 5
        TextBox1.Text = (Convert.ToString(random.Next(1, 5)))
        TextBox2.Text = (Convert.ToString(random.Next(1, 5)))

    Next

End Sub
```

But I can't use it to press the correct button. If the correct button is pressed the color changes. If not there are no changes. How can I do this. Please help me...

Note:

It is a board game. The game is played on a 4 by 4 grid To play the game, a player generates two random numbers and colors in an area on the grid indicated by the numbers. For example if the generated number is a 2 and a 3 the player clicks in the 2x3 square which results in the color of the square being changed. A player should only be able to click and change the color of the square represented by the random numbers only.

Comment: 2nd row and 3rd column in what?  a grid?  Your loop looks completely unnecessary.

Comment: I think we need a bit more information on this one to give a decent answer.

Comment: It is a board game. The game is played on a 4 by 4 grid

To play the game, a player generates two random numbers and colours in an area on the grid indicated by the numbers. For example if the generated number is a 2 and a 3 the player clicks in the 2x3 square which results in the colour of the square being changed. 

A player should only be able to click and change the colour of the square represented by the random numbers only.

Comment: Your title is confusing, the **used it in a C** part doesn't make any sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should create a class-level variable for both the row and column chosen:

```
Private randomRow as Integer
Private randomCol as Integer
```

Then in your code, assign the values:

```
Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    randomCol = random.Next(1, 5)
    randomRow = random.Next(1, 5)

    TextBox1.Text = randomCol.ToString()
    TextBox2.Text = randomRow.ToString()

End Sub
```

Now in your code the sees the user click a box, check to see if the box column and row are the same as the `randomCol` and `randomRow` variables.

Comment: Sorry  but Random Number Generator is not my question... well actually, what my question is: I've created a random generator with 2 textboxes. Each box will have a number between 1-4. After that two random numbers will be displayed in the textboxes. Lets say 2 and 3 are the random numbers. I would like to select the exact button the random numbers are specifying. If I click the button in 2nd Row and 3rd column then it should change colour. If I did not press the correct button then nothing should happen. So please help me.. I'm new to VB and programming..

Comment: Why do you put the col and row into textboxes? You should update your title to reflect what you're asking, and you should post more code. You need to trap the click event for the buttons, check to see if that button matches the desired row and column, if it does, do something, otherwise ignore it.